# What is a hypercomplex quantity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, terminology, probability, spinors

An extract from the book "Quantum Mechanics and the Path Integrals" by Richard P. Feynman and A. R. Hibbs:

> We can state the correct law for $P(x)$ mathematically by saying that $P(x)$ is the absolute square of a certain complex quantity (if electron spin is taken into account, it is a [hypercomplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_number) quantity) $\phi(x)$ which we call the *probability amplitude* of arrival at $x$.

What does **hypercomplex quantity** mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually "hypercomplex" means a quaternion, but he just means that the wavefunction at a point $x$ has two components $\psi_\uparrow(x)$ and $\psi_\downarrow(x)$
 with the probability density of being found at  $x$ being 
$$
P(x)= |\psi_\uparrow(x)|^2+ |\psi_\downarrow(x)|^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! Can you give good ref. to read more about Quaternions?

Comment: Thw wikipedia article "Quaternion" seems quite comprehensive.

Comment: I found [this video by 3blue1brown](https://youtu.be/d4EgbgTm0Bg) helpful.